# Importance of Web API Controller comparing with Class Library project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC 4.0. I recently underwent WEB API Controller.

**[AS per this link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)**, we can reuse our function at multiple places in the form of Web API Controller that returns data instead of View. Sorry for mentioning so obvious things.

**My Question is** : Web API Controller is only about reusability of the function in some website/Andriod etc ? If so, couldn't we use Class Library Project?

Answer (score 0):

A Web API Controller is a controller for a web service, which is very different from a Class Library project which you include in a project.

A web service is something you communicate with, you don't include it as an assembly in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can not publish your class library for public use while in case of web service you do.
You provide the URL of web service so that anyone can consume it while class library can be used within your project only.

Additional to above, web api has so many features that you can find at http://www.asp.net/web-api